# How to merge odt documents from the command line?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

I have a large number of odt reports in one folder.

How can I merge them into one odt document from the command line?

I have found that this was possible in [ooo_cat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025379/concatenating-opendocument-text-file-in-linux-from-the-command-line), but that seems deprecated (or at least I don't know where to start to use it).

Is it possible to merge odt documents from the command line? Does ooo_cat do the trick, if so, how can I install and use it?

Comment: also see http://ooopy.sourceforge.net/ :) what python version are you using? ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind Of course I've read that as well as http://sourceforge.net/projects/ooopy/, but I cannot find easy install and use instructions (also for future reference).

Comment: @Rinzwind python 2.7.6 and 3.4.0.

Comment: Also I want to avoid conflict between OO and LO.

Comment: Try with `libreoffice --print-to-file [OUTPUT FILE HERE] *.odt`

Comment: What about the messy all `odt`s to `txt`s, `cat` all `txt`s into one `txt` and convert that `txt` to `odt`?

Comment: @hakermania actually it is possible with pdf: convert all odt documents to pdf, then merge the pdfs, but that does not make the document editable. Converting to txt discards too much formatting.

Comment: You can't convert the pdf back to odt?

Comment: See http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/19222/how-to-merge-multiple-documents-into-single-merged-document/ or perhaps ask there as well.

Comment: @Rinzwind - almost right there - the recent versions [should work with Python 2.7,](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/OOoPy/) the problem is quite alot of the available versions seem to need the almost ancient Python 2.6 installed ... If searching for packages, you seem to need to search for `python-ooopy`

Comment: @user224082 this seems to just convert all files to pdf

Answer (score 6):

I had time to have a go at @Rinzwind's mentioned `ooopy` - to install it, download the latest version from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ooopy/), then extract it and run the `setup.py` as mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/2/install/) - or just run these commands to install the currently latest version 1.11:

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ooopy/ooopy/1.11/OOoPy-1.11.tar.gz
tar -xf OOoPy-1.11.tar.gz
cd OOoPy-1.11/
sudo python ./setup.py install
```

You can then use it like this:

```
ooo_cat file1.odt file2.odt file3.odt > file123.odt
```

this may also work:

```
ooo_cat file1.odt file2.odt file3.odt -o file123.odt
```

I have only tried it with three ODTs with small amounts of text.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 2.7.6.  Gave it a whirl with 25 separate one-page .odt documents, and it went well up until about page 16, where the formatting got all messed up after that.

Comment: @Andy - u could report it as a bug, or try merging them in smalls groups (say 5), and then merging those resulting groups.

Comment: OOoPy installation is also available through pip: ``pip install OOoPy``