# Concatenate LibreOffice documents

Tags: libreoffice, word-documents

I have few documents in LibreOffice that are separate documents (not forks). I need to concatenate them into a single document. Is there a menu for that? I am not talking about recording and merging independently made changes.

I tried just copy and paste of the whole text but it doesnt let me copy a text that has images in it. Having tables is also not helping.

Comment: You should be able to copy a text that has images in it. Anyway, does [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/482277/178596) help?

Comment: Throws an error: https://gist.github.com/arekbulski/a71ac74de9497d33e1d2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no explicit concatenation feature, but you could insert a whole document into another, keeping the entire content of both documents:

1. Just open Document 1,
2. move the cursor the position where Doc 2 should appear,
3. `Insert` ->  `File`
4. Select document 2 and hit <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Repeat to add more documents.

Comment: Nowadays step #3 is Insert -> Text from File

Comment: Also note that often, 2 different documents will have different Page formatting (margins, etc.), fonts, and Styles rules set up. So your newly-inserted document will often not look like it did when it existed on its own. That's fine, you'll just have to do some manual adjustments after they're combined, to make the two work together as a whole.